# node label expression in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use a scripted Jenkins Pipeline and want to define a label expression like `expr1 AND NOT expr2`.

So I used `node('expr1 && !expr2'){}`, but that (sometimes) allocated a node which does have both `expr1` and `expr2`.

I also tried with `node('expr1' && '!expr2'){}` but same result.

What is the correct syntax to say `expr1 AND NOT expr2` in scripted pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try (label1) && !(label2)

Koshuke details label improvements to Jenkins here (old):
https://jenkins.io/blog/2010/09/02/recent-label-and-matrix-project-improvement/

But it is perhaps better summarized here:
https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Jenkins_Job_Label_Expression

Operators

Specified in the descending order of precedence:

(expression) - defines the associativity of the expression.

!expression - negation.

a && b - AND, both expressions must true.

a || b - OR, either of the expression a or b may be true.

a -> b - "implies" operator, equivalent with !a || b. For example if "linux -> x64" expression is used, it is interpreted as follows: if a Linux agent is used, then the agent must be 64 bit.

a <-> b - "if and only if" operator, equivalent to a && b || !a && !b

Also, in the official docs:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node

Comment: We use this format for some jobs:
```node ("Label1 && !Label2")```
If you go to snippet generator (hostjenkins/pipeline-syntax) select step `Node: Allocate Node` there is some documentation there + you can generate your pipeline script step.

Comment: Thank you, but I made a stupid mistake: My label expression was correct, but I checked out my Jenkinsfile from the wrong branch...